# Why DRF modelserializers are returning 400 error code instead of 404, for the objects (foreign keys) they couldn't find?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404, django-serializer, http-status-code-400

I've been using modelserializers for a while, without noticing that when we enter an out-of-range id in request_body for foreign key fields, drf returns a 400 status code instead of 404!
Is it right to do so?
How can we change this behavior to return 404 status code in our modelserializers?

Comment: Are you using ModelViewSet or just the serializer?

Comment: @Walucas I'm using generic views and I set serialzier_class=my_serializer

Comment: Your get_queryset should give you a correct error code.

Comment: Try to use the DRF method `from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404`. Something like `user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)`.